# Long period of read timeouts calling Microsoft Graph API

Tags: timeout, microsoft-graph-api, availability

From 30 November 2019 0930 UTC we experienced a few hours of read timeouts calling the Microsoft Graph API attempting to download emails. Our read timeout is set at 30s and this is a call that in normal circumstances returns in about 1s. We make this call every 15 seconds. I was disappointed to see that no status page anywhere seemed to reflect this outage (are you monitoring your stuff Microsoft?).

By the way during this period none of the other external services that we call (just as frequently) had any problem so I'm ruling out a network glitch on our side.

Has anyone else experienced long periods of read timeouts using the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was a degradation of service that affected Microsoft Graph Exchange services around that time. This seems to have been resolved as indicated from this [post](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6462#issuecomment-562224301). 
Unfortunately Microsoft Graph doesn't have a health status page to be reporting on such occurrences, but this would be a really great addition.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, very helpful!